# Is there a tool I can use to convert SQL Server stored procedures to Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

Is there any tool to convert stored procedures used in Microsoft SQL Server to ones that are supported in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a tool](http://www.ispirer.com/customers) which will do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

All kidding aside, [these guys](http://www.swissql.com/products/sqlserver-to-oracle/sql-server-to-oracle.html) seem to offer a converter tool.

It looks though as it only converts from SQL Server 2000.